# Python copyfile() Permission denied

Tags: permission-denied, shutil, file-copying

I am trying to copy a file (sourcecode below), but on my console window I got the error: "PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\pathOfFile(Example)\Test.py'". I did it with following code:

```
from shutil import copyfile

copyfile("C:\someExamplePath\Test.py", "destinationPath")
```

The path to the files are correct for sure. Until now the file does not exist in my destination path. Is it necessary to create that file in my destination path before I try to copy it? and does it work with .exe file later? I want to have an executable file after I finished my project. Thanks

Comment: please check the permission for the logged in user or try to run cmd using administrator and then run the practical

Comment: thanks for the fast respond. Is it possible to copy .exe files aswell?

Comment: extension can be anything

Comment: ok and if the file does not exist in destination path, does copyfile() creates it automatic or do I have to do it before by my self

Comment: not exists at destination or source ??

Comment: in destination. The path of destination (C:\users\MyName\Desktop\) and of source does exist.
To copy a .txt file e.g.. Do I need to create a .txt file in destination folder with the same name (of the file I want to copy), which gets removed with the copy?

Comment: without source how can you copy file